# Ordenar DESC asp

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Tenho um grid na minha aplicação.
O código de uma coluna do grid é:

```
<Columns>
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="DATA_CADASTRO" SortExpression="DATA_CADASTRO"  HeaderText="Data Ativa&#231;&#227;o"
                            DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:BoundColumn>
```

Gostaria de definir o filtro dessa coluna com `DESC`, pois o padrão já é `ASC`.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Datagrid, adiciona `AllowSorting="True"`, e na coluna adiciona o DESC:

`<asp:BoundColumn DataField="DATA_CADASTRO" SortExpression="DATA_CADASTRO DESC" HeaderText="Data Ativa&#231;&#227;o" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}">`